# QT OpenGL QList of QVectors2D not Drawing correctly

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qlist, qvector

I am trying to use a QList of 2d Vectors to draw a series of non connecting lines/arcs and fade the colors the older they are in the list.

For Example:

```
void drawArcs(QList<QVector2D>& points,
               float centerX, float centerY,
               float red, float green, float blue)
{
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
float colorGain;
int INC;
INC=0;
colorGain=float(INC)/float(TotalArcPoints);
foreach (const QVector2D& vec, points)
{

    glColor3f(colorGain*red, colorGain*green, colorGain*blue);

    glVertex3f( vec.x() + centerX,
                    - vec.y() + centerY,
                    0.0);

    INC++;
    colorGain=float(INC)/float(TotalArcPoints);
}
glEnd();
}
```

However this connects all my arcs together I want each set of 2D vectors in the QList to be its own arch but when I change the code to this. It draws nothing and the screen is blank.

```
void drawArcs(QList<QVector2D>& points,
               float centerX, float centerY,
               float red, float green, float blue)
{

float colorGain;
int INC;
INC=0;
colorGain=float(INC)/float(TotalArcPoints);
foreach (const QVector2D& vec, points)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    glColor3f(colorGain*red, colorGain*green, colorGain*blue);

    glVertex3f( vec.x() + centerX,
                    - vec.y() + centerY,
                    0.0);

    INC++;
    colorGain=float(INC)/float(TotalArcPoints);
    glEnd();
}

}
```

The Color mapping is working correctly in the above code so I don't believe that is the problem. Im more confused as to why moving the glBegin/glEnd inside the for each loop causes nothing to be drawn.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function, there is only one vertex,

*so in the first function (of your code):* All the vertices are getting connected  between `glBegin` and `glEnd`.

*in the second function (of your code):* Between `glBegin` and `glEnd`, there is only one vertex. So you are not seeing any line.

**Now to fix your problem here is the pseudo code:**

two cases here

**Case 1:**

Assuming you want lines between the input points.
I mean, If your point vector has 4 points p1,p2,p3,p4.
First line is between p1 and p2.
Second line is between p3 and p4.

```
for(int i = 0; i<points.size(); i++)
{

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

    //FIRST POINT OF THE LINE
    glVertex3f( points.at(i).x() + center.x, 
                    - points.at(i).y() + center.y,
                    0.0);

    i = i + 1;

    //SECOND POINT OF THE LINE
    glVertex3f( points.at(i).x() + center.x, 
                    - points.at(i).y() + center.y,
                    0.0);
    glEnd();

}
```

**Case 2:**

Assuming you want lines between the centre and points.
I mean, If your point vector has 4 points p1,p2,p3,p4.
First line is between c and p1.
Second line is between c and p2.
Third line is between c and p3.
Fourth line is between c and p4.

```
for(int i = 0; i<points.size(); i++)
{

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

    //FIRST POINT OF THE LINE (CENTER)
    glVertex3f( center.x, center.y,0.0);

    //SECOND POINT OF THE LINE
    glVertex3f( points.at(i).x() + center.x, 
                    - points.at(i).y() + center.y,
                    0.0);
    glEnd();
}
```